# Determine TLS version when using SMPT in Amazon SES

Tags: smtp, amazon-ses

Amazon SES will soon stop supporting TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 in their SMTP interface.

We believe that a change in our code will force TLS 1.2 but we are not 100% sure.

How can we check on Amazon SES side if emails are sent with TLS 1.2?

We found https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/using-aws-cloudtrail-lake-to-identify-older-tls-connections-to-aws-service-endpoints/ but this seems to only apply to using TLS for the API endpoints, not for the SMTP interface.

Comment: I'd crank up logging and then send an email to yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Detecting Client IPs

AWS team will send out reminder email including details on the TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1 connections detected from your AWS account to SES using Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP). Or you can identify client IPs (server IPs hosted your application using SES) by yourself with [this AWS re:Post article](https://repost.aws/articles/ARevUPGDKvRyant5D1MA7yZg).

Checking TLS version

If you are not sure which TLS version is currently used by your application, I suggest to test by sending out a sample email. After you have received test email, you right click and find **View Source** for Outlook or **Show Original** for Gmail. Then you will know which TLS version you have been using as per below screenshot.

[image: Sample Image for TLS checking]

Change your code or not?

If your client software application was built after 2014 using AWS SDK, AWS CLI, JDK 8 or later, or another modern development environment, you do not need to update application code to use TLS 1.2. Otherwise, you will likely need to update. More details can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/tls-1-2-required-for-aws-endpoints/).

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but isnt the change for AWS related to them decomissioning requests to AWS SES SMTP server being < TLS 1.2. If currently a request is sent to AWS SES using TLS 1.0 it is accepted and then the actual email that is sent by AWS SES could then have TLS 1.2?

Comment: @jarm.dahl is right.  This isn't a good test.

Answer (score 0):

Your options vary depending on what environment your application is installed on and what language you are developing with. We went through this recently with multiple .NET applications on a Windows 2016 server.

Here are some options

Option 1 - Cloudwatch

- Add logging to Cloudwatch following these instructions https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/how-to-log-amazon-ses-details-using-amazon-cloudwatch/
- Send emails from all your applications
- Wait for AWS to send you a new email about TLS incompatibility. Compare the message IDs in that email with the ones in your Cloudwatch log to determine which emails are using the wrong version of TLS.

Option 2 - Packet sniffer

- Install a packet sniffer such as Wireshark. This picture filters requests to those containing "eu-west". You can then send emails and see if any use an old protocol.

[image: Wireshark filtering for AWS Emails]

Option 3 - Test Code

- Add some code to your application that makes a connection to a website that outputs the TLS version. Here is some C# code that makes a connection to https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check

```
using (var response = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check").GetResponse())
{
 using (var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
 {
  var output = streamReader.ReadToEnd();   
  Response.Write(output);
 }
}
```

To fix a .NET application on a Windows Server

1. Install IISCrypto and apply best practices https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto
2. Target .NET 4.7 or later see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls
3. If you really can't target .NET 4.7 then you can do the following dirty hack

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```